# How to make desktop notification larger or blink

Tags: html, notifications, desktop

So i got a job to make our desktop notification more noticeable. I'm already using sound on display but some users, wants a bigger visual notification. I have no idea how to make notification larger, or how to make it blink or something like that or maybe change background color.

Here is code that i use at the moment

```
if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() != 0)setAllowNotification();
    n = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('link/to/image.png', 'Warning!', 'Hey u got new important message');
    n.ondisplay=playSound();
    n.show();
```

It's used for admin of site so they know when user's do something, so it will not be used as spam for normal users.

Btw: There is no tag desktop-notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The notifications as provided by the browser are mostly out of your control as far as the extend they attract attention. Why? Because as you pointed out it could otherwise be misused (despite the fact the user has to give explicit permission for it). If you users want more attention attracting notifications the most valid way would be to show them in your own webpage, of course that also means that the user has to be on your webpage, but if that's where their focus lies then that should be fine. (And otherwise subtle desktop notifications are correct in being subtle, as they should distract too much from what the user is doing).

Comment: Ok thanks, so no way to do that. Problem is that user usualy dont have browser open(it's minimized) and they do some other work. They have a site open in a browser window. Is it possible to maximize browser?

Comment: Nope, it would once again go outside of the scope of what a browser is supposed to be allowed to do. Desktop notifications are *exactly* what you want in this situation, I honestly don't see how users are able to overlook these notifications... the only thing I would be able to suggest is having your users switch to firefox + mac + growl + https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/html-notification/ which would allow them to customize their own notifications... and a similar thing is possible on linux as well... but doubt that's within scope of the problem.

Comment: The problem is that those users are realy not at computer whole time, so i would need something like the whole screen flashing :D I think i will write .NET application and call it on actions.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it is, do they have mobile phones on them? And do I understand correctly that you're already using sound as well?

Comment: Yes I'm using sound i realy don't get ow can they miss it :S I think that they aren't the best workers on the world :D

Comment: You could have them pay up and send them SMS's using twilio :+ It's a pretty easy API so implementing it should be easy enough. I think using it you could even theoretically call them :P